# ruby api documentation, how to read

Tags: ruby, syntax

I don't know what this equates to in Ruby, as I've not come across nested arguments before:

`open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) → file`

How do I pass these three arguments? `open(['x','y'],'z')` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a shorthand way of describing many variants of the same function.

The square brackets indicate that a portion is optional. So in this instance it means you can use:

```
open(filename)
open(filename, mode)
open(filename, mode, perm)
open(filename, mode, opt)
open(filename, opt)
```

`Perm` is within two square brackets which means it's optional if `mode` is used but can't be used without `mode`.